# stuck in dependencies loop - ubuntu 22.04

Tags: apt, upgrade, dpkg, dependencies

im somehow ended up in package dependencies loop. when im trying to upgrade my packages following appears:

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree... Done
Reading state information... Done
You might want to run 'apt --fix-broken install' to correct these.
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 libapt-pkg6.0 : Depends: libgcrypt20 (>= 1.10.0) but 1.9.4-3ubuntu3 is installed
                 Depends: libzstd1 (>= 1.5.2) but 1.4.8+dfsg-3build1 is installed
                 Recommends: apt (>= 2.5.3) but 2.4.8 is installed
E: Unmet dependencies. Try 'apt --fix-broken install' with no packages (or specify a solution).
```

so i tried `sudo apt --fix-broken install`

```
sudo apt --fix-broken install
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree... Done
Reading state information... Done
Correcting dependencies... failed.
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 libapt-pkg6.0 : Depends: libgcrypt20 (>= 1.10.0) but 1.9.4-3ubuntu3 is installed
                 Depends: libzstd1 (>= 1.5.2) but 1.4.8+dfsg-3build1 is installed
                 Recommends: apt (>= 2.5.3) but 2.4.8 is installed
E: Error, pkgProblemResolver::Resolve generated breaks, this may be caused by held packages.
E: Unable to correct dependencies
```

then i tried to remove/purge the package `sudo apt purge libapt-pkg6.0:amd64`

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree... Done
Reading state information... Done
You might want to run 'apt --fix-broken install' to correct these.
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 apt : Depends: libapt-pkg6.0 (>= 2.4.8) but it is not going to be installed
 apt-utils : Depends: libapt-pkg6.0 (>= 2.4.8) but it is not going to be installed
 packagekit : Depends: libapt-pkg6.0 (>= 1.9.2) but it is not going to be installed
 python3-apt : Depends: libapt-pkg6.0 (>= 1.9.11~) but it is not going to be installed
 ubuntu-advantage-tools : Depends: libapt-pkg6.0 (>= 0.8.0) but it is not going to be installed
E: Unmet dependencies. Try 'apt --fix-broken install' with no packages (or specify a solution).
```

output of `apt policy libapt-pkg6.0`

```
libapt-pkg6.0:
  Installed: 2.5.3
  Candidate: 2.5.3
  Version table:
 *** 2.5.3 100
        100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
     2.4.8 500
        500 http://ch.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-updates/main amd64 Packages
     2.4.5 500
        500 http://ch.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy/main amd64 Packages
```

i tried other ways as well, but it seems that im stuck in this position. Any advice would be helpful.

Comment: @user535733 - done

Comment: thank you @user535733
when im trying to upgrade from 22.04 LTS to 22.10 with `sudo do-release-upgrade` i get this message: `Checking for a new Ubuntu release
Please install all available updates for your release before upgrading.
`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ok, i think i found a solution:

first i used:

```
sudo dpkg -r --force-depends libapt-pkg6.0:amd64
```

to remove the package despite dependencies

then i downloaded the correct version:

```
wget http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/a/apt/libapt-pkg6.0_2.4.5_amd64.deb
```

then installed it:

```
sudo dpkg -i libapt-pkg6.0_2.4.5_amd64.deb
```

reboot the system and after that the update and upgrade was working again

Comment: @user535733 what do you think about that solution? legit? or was i just lucky?

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you installed 22.10 (kinetic) packages onto a 22.04 (jammy) system at some point.

libapt-pkg6.0 in 22.10 = version 2.5.3.

Lesson: Never mix packages from different releases of Ubuntu unless you are expert.

You have three options:

1. If you don't know how that happened, and/or do not want to spend a few hours learning how to fix it, then time to reinstall 22.04 (or 22.10).
2. Alternately, another solution is to resume using 22.10. This is more complex, because you cannot use `do-release-upgrade` anymore, since your packages have unmet dependencies. Whether or not this is possible depends upon how much damage you have caused, how you caused it, and whether or not you have the skills to repair it. It requires manually fixing your sources, and then using `dist-upgrade`. It's not a supported upgrade path, so if you encounter problems with it, our advice will be to reinstall.
3. The most complex and highest-skill solution is to uninstall all the 22.10 packages and reinstall from the 20.04 repositories. This solution has a learning curve and requires some skill with apt. It is almost certainly faster and simpler to reinstall.

Comment: spending a few hours and learning something sounds good.
do you have any starting point or reading material?